# How to create a nested web service in Business Central with Page Parts?

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I've created this API page in Business Central:

```
page 60012 CustomerPL
{
    PageType = API;
    EntitySetName = 'customerPLs';
    EntityName = 'customerPL';
    APIPublisher = 'MyCompany';
    APIGroup = 'MyCompany';
    SourceTable = "Customer";
    InsertAllowed = false;
    ModifyAllowed = false;
    DeleteAllowed = false;

    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(Group)
            {
                field("Cliente"; Rec."No.")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                }
                part(partCustomerBanksPL; 60013)
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                    EntitySetName = 'partCustomerBanksPLs';
                    EntityName = 'partCustomerBanksPL';
                    SubPageLink = "Customer No." = field("No.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to have a Customer web service with banks, addresses, etc. in a nested json following [this guide](https://www.kauffmann.nl/2020/05/05/deep-insert-with-business-central-apis/)

This is the ListPart:

```
page 60013 partCustomerBanksPL
{
    ApplicationArea = All;
    Caption = 'Bancos clientes PL';
    PageType = ListPart;
    SourceTable = "Customer Bank Account";
    
    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(General)
            {
                field("Code"; Rec."Code")
                {
                }
                field(Name; Rec.Name)
                {
                }
                field(IBAN; Rec.IBAN)
                {
                }
                field("SWIFT Code"; Rec."SWIFT Code")
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the GET request:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{{tenant_id}}/Sandbox_PL/ODataV4/Company('MyCompany')/customerPL?$expand=partCustomerBanksPL
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'partCustomerBanksPL' on type 'NAV.customerPL'.  CorrelationId:  34fca7a0-ae62-4218-90f1-09ad53e0cfc0."
    }
}
```

So... How can I create a nested web service in Business Central with Page Parts like I'm trying?

EDIT: code updated to match names and camelCase

Comment: In your example, there is no CustomerPL object. Instead use customerWS and make sure to use camelCase for all entity properties. Have a look at this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-custom-api#to-create-api-pages-to-display-car-brand-and-car-model

Comment: renamed everything to match and with camelCase but didn't change anything, still getting the same error, code of the question is updated you can check

Comment: Looks OK except that your EntityName and EntitySetName are identical. Usually, EntityName is singular, the name of one instance of the published object, and the EntitySetName is plural.

Comment: Updated again, nothing changed... same error, trying to access $expand=partCustomerBanksPL and $expand=partCustomerBanksPLs but nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the APIVersion property

```
page 60012 CustomerPL
{
    ...
    APIPublisher = 'MyCompany';
    APIGroup = 'MyCompany';
    APIVersion = 'v1.0';
    ...
```

and use the following HTTP request: [https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/>tenant_id](https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/%3Etenant_id)</Sandbox_PL/api/MyCompany/MyCompany/v1.0/companies(>companyId<)/customerPLs?$expand=partCustomerBanksPLs

EDIT: Take a look at the official MS documentation on
*Creating API pages*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-custom-api#to-create-api-pages-to-display-car-brand-and-car-model

Answer (score 1):

page 60013 partCustomerBanksPL also needs to be an API page.

```
page 60013 CustomerBankAccountAPI
{
    APIGroup = 'apiGroup';
    APIPublisher = 'publisherName';
    APIVersion = 'v2.0';
    ApplicationArea = All;
    Caption = 'customerBankAccountAPI';
    DelayedInsert = true;
    EntityName = 'customerBankAccount';
    EntitySetName = 'customerBankAccounts';
    PageType = API;
    SourceTable = "Customer Bank Account";
    
    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(General)
            {
                field("code"; Rec."Code")
                {
                    Caption = 'Code';
                }
                field(name; Rec.Name)
                {
                    Caption = 'Name';
                }
                field(iban; Rec.IBAN)
                {
                    Caption = 'IBAN';
                }
                field(swiftCode; Rec."SWIFT Code")
                {
                    Caption = 'SWIFT Code';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to update the part on your Customer API.

```
part(partCustomerBanksPL; CustomerBankAccountAPI)
{
    EntitySetName = 'customerBankAccount';
    EntityName = 'customerBankAccounts';
    SubPageLink = "Customer No." = field("No.");
}
```